# nHibernate on IIS 7, SQLClientPermissionException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, iis-7

I am developing an MVC application using nHibernate; running through VS's built in web server the application runs without errors.  When setup and running through IIS7 on localhost, the application throws a SQlClientPermission exception after calling System.Data.SqlClient.PermissionDemand (SqlClient calls this internally)

I have enabled the application to run under full trust but it doesn't seem to affect the outcome.

Comment: Do you provide an SQL username and password in the connection string?  What authentication mode\s did you define in your web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description, I'm guessing that you're using Integrated Security in your connection string. Maybe something along the lines below.

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

When running through VS built in web server, it runs under your credentials and that's why it works.

To get this to work on IIS, either

1. Create a new IIS app pool which runs
   under your credentials
2. Or, use sql authentication.

(Let me know if you like me to expand further)

Comment: I'm using SQL authentication for this project. I have also tried creating an app pool with all credentials for the local machine, but to no avail.